# get xy position of drag and drop jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am creating a drag and drop web application using asp.net.

this is my sample layout:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                   STAGE DROP AREA                  |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------+
|  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  |
|< |IMG A |  |IMG B |  |IMG C |  |IMG D |  |IMG E | >|
|  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

All image in the second panel (IMG A..E) are draggable in the stage. My problem now is every time I drag the image it goes first in the upper left corner of the stage.

This is my code for drag and drop:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".Images").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    scroll: false
});

$("#stage").droppable({
    accept: ".Images",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('copied')) return
        var droppedItem = $(ui.draggable).clone().addClass('copied');
        droppedItem.draggable({
            containment: "#stage"
        });
        $(this).append(droppedItem);
    }
});

});
```

this is my css for the stage:

```
.stageCSS{
 position:absolute;
 width:640px;
 height:376px;
 top: 124px;
 left: 84px;
}
```

this is the source of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ufHMm/

Comment: ok, and where do you want the images to go ? to a fixed position?

Comment: Where I drop the image but it must be inside the stage.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you would like to drop the items inside the box to the exact position of your cursor.

To do so, add an absolute positioning to the items, a relative positioning to the container, calculate the coordinates, than set the items' top and left css properties.

Jquery:

```
 ...
    $(this).append(droppedItem);
    var posX = ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left;
    var posY = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;
    droppedItem.css("left", posX);
    droppedItem.css("top",posY);
    ...
```

Css:

```
.box {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background: orange;
    position: relative;    
}
.copied
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/er144/3Hay4/

Comment: It works on the first image, but after that it just drops the images kind off randomly. You need to restart the posX

Comment: You're right, in IE behaves differently. Sorry, I only tested it under FF, and there it works. I'll take a look later, to see what's wrong.